# pySerial: Does write_timeout do anything?

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm wondering if `write_timeout` even works or if I have to handle the timeout myself.
I want to send data to my STM32 Nucleo-Board via UART. For that I'm using the library `pySerial`. But if the write operation fails, because the Nucleo-Board isn't powered, I want to throw an error saying "Nucleo-Board not powered". I assume that when the write operation times out after 1 second, the Nucleo-Board has no power. So, I set the `write_timeout` of the `serial.Serial()` object to `1`, but it seems that `write_timeout` doesn't do anything.

I created my own class, to add additional methods.

```
class Serial:

    def __init__(self, baudrate: int, port: str, write_timeout: int = None, read_timeout: int = None):
        self.baudrate = baudrate
        self.port = port
        self.write_timeout = write_timeout
        self.read_timeout = read_timeout

        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        self.ser.baudrate = self.baudrate
        self.ser.port = self.port
        self.ser.write_timeout = self.write_timeout
        self.ser.timeout = self.read_timeout


    def _serial_ports():
        # ...

    def serialWrite(self, string: str, size: int = None):
        print(self.write_timeout)
        print(self.ser.write_timeout)

        # check if COM port exists -> because UART cable is connected, COM6 always exists, 
        # even when no power is connected.
        if self.port not in self._serial_ports(): 
            raise serial.SerialException(f"Make sure this COM Port exists.")

        try:
            print("opened")
            self.ser.open()
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            print("closed")
            self.ser.close()

            # error handling ...
            
        else:
            encodedString = string.encode()
            print("write now")
            try:
                bytes = self.ser.write(encodedString)  # times out here -> program hangs (no exception)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print("Nucleo-Board not powered")


serialPort = Serial(baudrate=115200, port="COM6", write_timeout=1)
feedback = serialPort.serialWrite(f"ABC", 3)
```

Output

```
self.write_timeout=1
self.ser.write_timeout=1
opened
write now
```

I have to kill the program, because it stops working.
The program works, when I plug in the power of the Nucleo-Board.

Comment: The board being unpowered doesn't prevent serial data from being sent - it just means the data isn't going anywhere.  So there's no possibility of a timeout, unless hardware handshaking is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The problem was, that I thought the timeout happens on `ser.write()`. But a timeout never happens on `ser.write()`, because (as @jasonharper already commented) the board being unpowered doesn't prevent serial data from being sent - it just means the data isn't going anywhere. So in the end, the timeout was a few lines after the write operation at the read operation `ser.read()`, to get a feedback to know the Nucleo-Board received something. There it can timeout, because it waits until data are received. But the board isn't powered so data will never received. Because I didn't handled the timeout for read operations, the program started to hang.

##### Current Code

```
try:
    bytes = self.ser.write(encodedString)
except Exception as e:
    # never raise
    print(e)
    print("Nucleo-Board not powered")

feedback = self.ser.read(size) # here it waits forever, because it doesn't receive something of course, because the Nucleo board isn't powered.
```

##### Code Solution

```
self.ser.timeout = 1 # for self.ser.read()
```